# PHP forward and backward for loop verse

Tags: php

I could make first verse to write but I want next verse to be written backwards however I can't do it.

```
<?php
$russian[]="En";
$russian[]="liten";
$russian[]="vektor";
$russian[]="ar";
$russian[]="ett";
$russian[]="exempel";
$russian[]="pa";
$russian[]="och";
$russian[]="falt";
for ($soviet=0;$soviet<sizeof($russian);$soviet++)
echo $russian[$soviet]." ";
for ($soviet=5;$soviet<sizeof($russian);$soviet=$soviet-1)
echo $russian[$soviet]." ";
?>
```

Comment: you are going to need to include a better description/question for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Please note that using such clause (`$soviet<sizeof($russian)`) for condition in `for` loop is not efficient. You will not notice the difference now, but for larger arrays do `$size = sizeof($russian)` before the loop and then use condition `$soviet<$size` in the loop (now `sizeof($russian)` is executed on every `for` loop).

Comment: So it means that it counts all rows in array 9 times in loop?

Comment: `echo implode(' ', array_reverse($russian));`

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to display the words from the last to the first, you could use:

```
for ($soviet = count($russian); $soviet > 0; --$soviet)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
for ($soviet=sizeof($russian)-1; $soviet >= 0; $soviet--)
  echo $russian[$soviet]." ";
```

you have to test for >= 0, because the first word is in $russian[0]

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this:

```
for ($soviet=count($russian);$soviet>0;$soviet--)
```

Not sure what you mean by verse, though. You want print out that array twice, once forward, and once backward, so you end up with

```
En liten vektor ar ett exempel pa och falt falt och pa exempel ett ar vektor liten En
```

?

Comment: I want it to write. En liten vektor ar ett exempel pa och falt falt och pa exempel ett ar vektor liten. And then write the sentence the other way around. liten vektor ar ett exempel pa och....

Comment: Heheh, I noticed your edit, before your comment and deleted my comment. Now we're all backwards!

Answer (score 1):

If you have such a small array, I would not bother with constructing the right `for` conditions.
Instead use:

```
foreach (array_reverse($russian) as $word) {
```